# how can use two or three AR session configurations parallel ie ( ARWorldTracking and ARBodyTracking )

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

(note : My scanning method is to keep scanning device stable and let target body move in circular manner to scan complete body)

I want to scan a human in 3D in which I need depth data which I get from ARWorldTracking configuration to generate PCD and simultaneously I also want human body movements to be tracked using ARBodyTracking so I can align the PCD according to body rotates try to stitch according to it

please suggest me any idea how to do above task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you want is to be able to scan something (a human here) in different poses to make a point cloud from angles that you could not normally reach easily ?

Sadly you cant have several AR sessions run in parallel. But switching sessions is very fast. My guess is that you would have to separate those steps into a free-move body tracking time and a no-move scanning time.

Scenario Idea:

> -> Start the `tracking` process.
>
> -> Your model can freely move, decide of a pose to adopt.
>
> -> Once the body position was acquired by `tracking`, start a `scan` session. The model has to not move.
>
> -> Once you're happy with the data from this pose, stop `scan` session, and make the app come back to `tracking`.
>
> -> Either start a new `scan` after having found a new pose you like, or stop the full process.

Also, I am not sure if the body tracking + the accuracy of the LiDAR combined will give you a satisfying result if you merge data from different poses. With the scenario I'm thinking about, you can display the merged PCD and you're always able to easily drop data from a specific pose you disliked.